# Infimum depending on two variables

Tags: supremum-and-infimum

How can I calculate the supremum of the infimum of a function depending on two variables?

For example:

$$
\begin{align*}
   a =\sup_{t \geq 0} \left\{ \inf_{r \geq 0}  \{ 10 \leq t + r \} \right\} 
\end{align*}
$$

What I would have done is calculating the infimum first, only depending on `r` and then  the supremum only depending on `t`.

This would give me $a = 10$. Is that correct?

Comment: Is $\leq$ a typo here?

Comment: If $10\leq t+r$ is supposed to be $10-t+r$ then your answer is correct.

Comment: The $\leq$ is correct. Would it make sense when defined for natural numbers?

Comment: Does it even make any sense in its current form?

Comment: What's your opinion? The inf of something is roughly the minimum value it can take (I'll leave the details for now, there are other concerns). What is the minimum value of $10\le t+r$? How is $10\le t+r$ even a *value*? How does it make any sense?

Comment: @maax The only way I can see of making any sense of the expression $\ \inf_{r \geq 0}  \{ 10 \leq t + r \}\ $ is to interpret it as $\ \inf \{r\,\vert\, r\ge0\mbox{ and }10 \leq t + r \}\ $, but, in my opinion, it is certainly *not* a reasonable way of expressing this latter meaning.